# jquery .on() event map on dynamic elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a dynamically created form inside the element `#addform` with input fields. I am attaching events to the fields like so:

```
$('input[type=text]').on({focus:function(){console.log('d');}},'#addform')
```

**Why does this not trigger?** I read about `.delegate()` but I think it's supposed to work with `.on()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the arguments reversed.  It should be:

```
$("#addform").on({...}, 'input[type=text]');
```

The reason for this is that the actual binding is done to `#addform`.  `input[type=text]` may not exist when `.on` is called.

Comment: thanks. makes sense. as soon as SO lets me, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more appropriate:

```
$('#addform').on({focus:function(){console.log('d');}},'input[type=text]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addform').on('focus','input[type=text]', function(){
   console.log('d');
});
```

Does the same thing but is more readable I think.